# Avoiding special characters with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python script to extract metadata from a PDF user pyPdf.

The output is something like this:

```
{'/Subject': u'Presentation from the 2011 Water Program Peer Review',
 '/Producer': u'Mac OS X 10.7.2 Quartz PDFContext', 
 '/Creator': u'PowerPoint', 
 '/ModDate': u"D:20120109085812-07'00'", 
 '/Keywords': u'', 
 '/Title': u'Wind Wave Float', 
 '/CreationDate': 'D:20111030043455Z'}
```

I only need the `title` and `subject` fields, so the printed output would ideally be:

Wind Wave Float, Presentation from...

So I can easily input the data into a spreadsheet.

Can anyone help me with some regex?  I can't seem to figure out how to get it done with all of the weird characters in the output.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your output if you `print` that dictionary object ?

Comment: That dictionary object is the printed output in the terminal.

Comment: are you sure that if you explicitly print the dictionary that is the output, with `print mydictionary` ?

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? Doesn't pyPDF give you python objects which you can access directly?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just started using the module and I'm not clear on all of the intricacies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're looking at is a dictionary, so the information you want is already available.  The 'u' that you see in the output dictionary indicates that the string is Unicode format.

I think the easy way to proceed to reach your goal of getting the information into a spreadsheet, is to just add the following in your script:

(in Python 2.x):

```
print outputdict['/Title'] + ", " + outputdict['/Subject']
```

This will give you output:

```
Wind Wave Float, Presentation from...
```

(replace outputdict above with whatever object is providing the dictionary output you've pasted in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?i)((?<=subject': u')[^']+|(?<=title': u')[^']+)
```

This regex will match `Presentation from the 2011 Water Program Peer Review` and `Wind Wave Float` from

```
{'/Subject': u'Presentation from the 2011 Water Program Peer Review', '/Producer': u'Mac OS X 10.7.2 Quartz PDFContext', '/Creator': u'PowerPoint', '/ModDate': u"D:20120109085812-07'00'", '/Keywords': u'', '/Title': u'Wind Wave Float', '/CreationDate': u'D:20111030043455Z'}
```

It is basically matching anything after `subject': u'` or `/Title': u'` that isnt a `'`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, this works perfectly on Debuggex, however I'm having trouble getting it to properly run in the script.  Can you help me figure out how to properly input it?

output = re.match('therexex', string) is returning a syntax error.

Comment: Not going to lie regex I know python I dont. In other languages the regex itself will have characters that need escaping, for instance int c# this regex '\.' will have to be '\\.'  to escape the backslash or '\.\.' can be @'\.\.' which will become '\\.\\.' The @ escapes all special characters in the string. I believe in python you have re.escape()? Which it seems behaves similarly to @ as I just described? Trying do something along the lines of: x=re.escape(regex); output = re.match(x, string).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
'/(Subject|Title)':\s+u('[^']+'|"[^"]+")(?=, )
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

https://www.debuggex.com/r/k78fFPfoaOofugig